# How to call certain methods and return certain objects based on class type

Tags: java, database, sqlite, class, instantiation

Normally I try to use polymorphism to avoid using things like `instanceof`, and I don't like using ORM frameworks because they often cause me a lot more headache than they're worth, so I tried to make my own database class with simple features.

Some of you are probably giggling, "See, ORMs exist for a reason, don't roll your own!" but I'm not trying to make a full-blown ORM; just something lightweight for my specific use that does what I need (cue more giggling, I know).

Right now I am hitting this issue:

Normally when doing a select statement from an SQLiteDatabase when creating objects from the data tables, you use a `Cursor` object, iterate over the records, and instantiate an object in the loop.

Consider a Dog class that extends MyDatabaseClass.

Is it considered bad practice to do something like this:

```
public Cursor getDogCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    return database.query(Dog.TABLE_NAME, Dog.COLS, null, null, null, null, null);
}

public Cursor getCursor(Class<? extends MyDatabaseClass>) {
    if (clazz == Dog.class) return getDogCursor();
    //...
    return null;
}

public Dog getDogFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    String dogId = getLongFromColumnName(cursor, Dog._ID);
    String dogName = getStringFromColumnName(cursor, Dog.COL_NAME);
    return new Dog(dogId, dogName);
}

public MyDatabaseClass getDatabaseObjectFromCursor(Class<? extends MyDatabaseClass> clazz, Cursor cursor) {
    if (clazz == Dog.class) return getDogFromCursor(cursor);
    //...
    return null;
}

public List<? extends MyDatabaseClass> getList(Class<? extends MyDatabaseClass> clazz) {
    Cursor cursor = getCursor(clazz);
    List<MyDatabaseClass> list = new ArrayList<>();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(getDatabaseObjectFromCursor(clazz, cursor);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
```

}

So now if I want to get a list of Dogs I can do

```
List<Dog> dogList = (List<Dog>) myDatabaseInstance.getList(Dog.class);
```

or make it a static method of the Dog class if need be.

Is this considered a valid approach, or is it considered dangerous to do that class comparison like this? I would have loved to use polymorphism somehow but I couldn't see any good way to do it on account of there being different fields for different classes with different constructors.

Comment: With what you are trying to do - this is perfectly fine. This is what all orm tools do as well - convert a generic resultset into a specific set of objects. Only difference is the mapping is externalized in some xml file or annotation takes care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you supply the data type, you can use generics.

```
    public <T extends MyDatabaseClass> List<T> getList(Class<T> clazz) {
        Cursor cursor = getCursor(clazz);
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            list.add((T) getDatabaseObjectFromCursor(clazz, cursor));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: What does this allow me to do that my current code does not? Avoid the casting later? edit: After trying this, it does not appear to compile. It doesn't like the line where the object is added to the list. I even tried changing the getDatabaseObject method to use <T extends MyDatabaseClass> but nothing.

Comment: Do I have to change the getDatabseObject method to something like `public <T extends MyDatabaseClass> T getDatabaseObject(Class<T> clazz, Cursor cursor) { if (clazz == Dog.class) return (T) getDogFromCursor(cursor); }` ?

Comment: You don't need to change `getDatabaseObjectFromCursor()`, since it return `MyDatabaseClass`.

Comment: If you try that code as written, it will not compile

Comment: If want to avoid the unchecked inspection, you can updated `getDatabaseObjectFromCursor()` as you suggested : `public <T extends MyDatabaseClass> T getDatabaseObject(Class<T> clazz, Cursor cursor) { if (clazz == Dog.class) return (T) getDogFromCursor(cursor); }`

Answer (score 0):

How about it would look like this:

```
List<Dog> dogList = new DogRepository(myDatabaseInstance).getList();
```

Its much better then `if (clazz == Dog.class)` and you can use polymorphism having some BaseRepository with common methods.

Comment: What would be inside the DogRepository exactly? I'd still want getList() to be part of the BaseRepository. Would DogRepository only have things like getDogCursor and such?

Comment: BaseRepository could have abstract `getItemFromCursor` and DogRepository should implement it like you do in `getDogFromCursor`

Comment: Same for `getItemCursor` - call base method with `Dog.TABLE` and `Dog.COLS` params. Or declare abstract methods `getTableName` and `getColumnNames` and implement them in DogRepository